# Issue with rsync: tput warning

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync to copy files from one server to the other and I keep getting this warning:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

The command I run is this:

```
rsync -aq --log-file="/path/to/log" -e "ssh -i /path/to/private/key" /folder/to/copy/ user@server:/folder/to/copy/to
```

It doesn't affect the rsync command, and all the files get copied correctly, but it's quite annoying to see the warning coming out about 4 or 5 times whenever I run the command.

I have tried googling it but I can't seem to find anyone else with the same problem.

Also, the warning appears on different servers, as well as when I use the command locally.

Could somebody please explain why this happens, or how to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `TERM` variable set to a valid value for the terminal type you are using.

It's highly unusual that you don't already - what OS is this?